# Error parsing configurationjava.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android, file, nullpointerexception, genymotion

In genymotion when i am running application then at time of installation of app in genymotion these exception is coming , I am pasting logcat error  here:

```
 Error parsing configurationjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

These is also expansion of same exception here ,

```
E/WifiStateMachine﹕ Failed to reload STA firmware java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: command '1 softap fwreload eth1 STA' failed with '501 1 SoftAP command has failed'
```

Now these are also same kind of thing ,

```
Desktop items loading interrupted:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.checkItemPlacement(LauncherModel.java:1211)
            at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.loadWorkspace(LauncherModel.java:1368)
            at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.loadAndBindWorkspace(LauncherModel.java:1005)
            at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.run(LauncherModel.java:1111)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

although it does not causes error but these happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first exception it can be happens because of launching of your genymotion and it is getting configured with your wi-fi .
Now in your second exception because of some items of app loading of your genymotion .
and it is getting null at there .
These all exception will not put any problem in execution of your app and work .